# NSSring from plist created from NSArray

Tags: ios

I create a NSArray and write to a file: a.plist.
 I use NSString: initWithContentsOfFile, and I can see the content in xml.

Then, I add a.plist to another project
and then I use NSString: initWithContentsOfFile to get the xml string.

```
filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *plistStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

However, it failed to recreate the xml string.
I user NSArray to test:

```
NSArray *plist2Array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

But it successfully.

I think it may result from "Text Encoding" when I add it to another project.
The problem is I tried UTF8,UTF16 and so on.
I still can't find solution.

Hope for your help,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it!
rename the file: a.plist ->a.txt(or any else),
then in another project you can get the xml string.